# Please help me with Queryable.select

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I fix this error ?

```
>     Type arguments for method Queryable.Select<TSource>,<TResult> .... 
>     cannot be inferred from the usage. 
>     Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

This is my code

```
Comments = e.Comments.AsQueryable().Select(CommentViewMode.ViewModel)
```

It shows the red squiggly line on 'Select'

Answer (score 0):

Minnie,

The LINQ `Select` extension method for `IQueryable` takes a function as an argument.  The [documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Queryable_Select__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___) shows the signature and a simple example:

```
List<int> range =
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

// Project the square of each int value.
IEnumerable<int> squares =
    range.AsQueryable().Select(x => x * x);
```

So the `Select` method expects a function that takes an argument of the same type as your queryable enumerates.  In the example above, it is an `int`.  In the code you provided it will be the type of one of your `Comments` elements.  I expect you need to write your select like this:

`var something = e.Comments.AsQueryable().Select(x => x.SomePropertyOfYourCommentClass)`